# C# Array of TextBoxes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am writing in WPF Sudoku and I need an Array of TextBoxes.
I have 81 textboxes their names is starts with txt11, txt21, txt31, that means that the first txt in line 1 and column 1, second txt in line 1 and column 2 ...etc.

My code is:

```
private TextBox[,] texts = new TextBox[9, 9];

void Initialization_text()
    {

        texts[0, 0] = txt11;
        texts[0, 1] = txt21;
        texts[0, 2] = txt31;
        texts[0, 3] = txt41;
        texts[0, 4] = txt51;
        texts[0, 5] = txt61;
        texts[0, 6] = txt71;
        texts[0, 7] = txt81;
        texts[0, 8] = txt91;

..................
}
```

but I want it like this:

```
void Initialization_text()
   {

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                texts[i, j] = (TextBox)Control["txt" + j+i];//j will be the column and i will be the line
            }
        }
```

but it does not work.
and I dont know how to solve it

Comment: What do you mean "not work"? Do you get an error? Are you not getting the expected behavior?

Comment: You should consider using MVVM instead on keeping track of TextBox controls.

Comment: What do you mean _its not work_? Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: texts[i, j] = new TextBox();
                    texts[i, j].Text = "txt" + (j+1).ToString() + (i+1).ToString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
private TextBox[,] texts = new TextBox[9, 9];
```

you initialize array of "pointers", where every pointer is initialized to null.
You must initialize every instance of the class also !

In your For loop you should do something like this :

```
texts[i,j] = new TextBox();
texts[i,j].text = "txt" + i.ToString() + j.ToString();
```

Comment: Given his first example, it would appear that he has created all 81 textboxes through the designer, so they do already exist.

Comment: Oh, maybe i didn't understood the question.

Comment: that's just not true...

Comment: OopsUser Thanks... your solution is that i need. You understood my question

Comment: Zdravko danev, what is not true ? She said it solved her problem

Answer (score -1):

```
Control["txt" + j.ToString() + i.ToString()]
```

Comment: This won't change a thing.  `"txt"` will be concated with `j` first, then concated to `i`.  `i+j` isn't computed first.

Comment: you don't need (i+j) computed

Comment: You're right, he doesn't.  And he isn't doing that now.  This code will have exactly the same output as the OP, but it just uses more code to do it.  Operators are applied from left to right, not right to left.